# How to loop code without setting a definite ending in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I have a frame that has actions in it.  The code isn't in a function and as such it loops. Now that I added a new scene it just immediately jumps to the new scene. Is there a loop I can use that it only executes until a collision happens between player1 and thisBall?

Comment: **Don't use scenes!** They just cause trouble.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

As null commented, don't use scenes (they really are a bag of hurt).  In spite of that, you appear to be needing a game loop.  This is common enough...

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
function onEnter(e:Event):void {
    //do stuff
}
```

The way you need to think of it is like looking at a video.  Each "frame" you're running some logic, such as `ball.x += 1;` which would move the ball to the right of the screen, each time the screen updates (a.k.a., a new "frame").  If you wanted to do something else when your condition was met, you could add it to your loop logic.

```
function onEnter(e:Event):void {
    ball.x += 1;

    if (ball.x == player.x) {
        trace("You've hit the player with the ball.")
    }
}
```

This is very rudimentary, and I wouldn't tackle it this way if you're using classes, or a larger framework, but this should get you by for now.

Comment: I think the heart of the OP's question was how to stop the playhead until the collision was detected, not how to detect a collision.

Comment: I'd argue the question was directed at how to test a condition on a scene that's looping as a factor of time.  Honestly, `x == x` is a terrible collision test, but it did serve to exemplify the conditional requested.

Answer (score 0):

If in your root timeline, you have two MovieClips, one on frame 1 and one on frame 2, you can have this in your main document Class:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
   public function Main() {
       super();
       stop();
       addEventListener('collision', onCollision);
   }
   private function onCollision(e:Event) {
       nextFrame();
   }
}
```

Then, anywhere in the MC on frame 1 (hopefully in an attached Class), you can have this code:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event('collision', true));
```

Your main document Class will "hear" that event and go to the next frame, which will contain whatever you want to see next.

Comment: I'll be surprised if the user even know what a document class is and how to use it.

Comment: It's not difficult to find, and I'm not going to assume the OP can't figure that out if he/she doesn't already know. It's certainly something that anyone who expects to be doing Flash for a living should be aware of.